# Identifying Memory Leak in Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am trying to understand memory leak in the android app using android studio tools and mat.

I have taken a screen shot of android studio while running app and another after clicking GC button.

Now as a beginner in analysing memory leaks or using android studio tools for that matter I would like to understand the graphs below.

How can I determine by just looking at the graphs that my app has leaked memory?

In Image 1 - I opened my app landed on the HomeScreen went to a different activity performed an action (saving an image) then returned back.

In Image 2 - I clicked on the GC button.

Is my app leaking memory ? If no, are my steps proper or are there any specific steps to follow to check for memory leaks.

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Kindly help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Android performance improvement tips](http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2017/01/some-thoughts-on--android-app-performance.html)

Learn how to generate heap dump(.hprof file) for objects allocation tracking.
go to Analyzer Tasks tab (left side in Android studio) There you will find leaked activities.
[image: Please check image]
whenever there is a cut like above images in graph, there is garbage collection.
You need to identify leaked activities. 
This is best link, which explains how to do memory profiling in android studio using different tools.
[UDI COHEN BLOGPOST](http://blog.udinic.com/2015/09/15/speed-up-your-app)

Also you should check heap dump. if you close app and some objects from your app are still floating out there is garbage collection.

Also if you open close an activity multiple times, and heap size keeps growing every time you open activity, there is must memory leakage.

Comment: Can u point out to a graph which is supposed to be ideal than the one which has leaks ? It will be helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: added image as example.

Comment: I identify the leaked activity, but how can I know which object inside the activity not being garbage collected causing the leak?

Comment: Oh, I see. Open the dump .hprof(converted to standard format) on MAT can identify it

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine whether your app is leaking memory you must take a snapshot of your memory and dump the heap and check the allocation in the captures window